# CSS animation flickers on mobile browser

Tags: cordova, css-animations, mobile-webkit

If you visit [this webpage](http://numediaweb.com/tmp/5/#/main_screen), in your laptop/mac the animation works as it should, but if you visit it using your android phone (I tested it in Android 2.3) you will notice a flicker in the animation!

Being aware of the `backface-visibility` but it has no effect :(

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
```

Any suggestions to get it working on Android (this is actually meant as a game for PhoneGap app).

Does it have anything to do with Anglularjs animate/ngShow?

Comment: Animation w/ Android 2.3.x is terrible. We ended up removing it from our app. There really is no solution to this.

Comment: I tested it also on Android 4.3.1 browser and it **bugs** too!